# Get AVPlayer that is current playing the audio

Tags: iphone, ios, avplayer

I am using an `AVPlayer`, and I would like the user to be able to leave the screen that is controlling the audio, then come back to it with the same audio playing. I have accomplished this, but I can't seem to regain control of the `AVPlayer` that is currently playing the audio. It there a call that allows me to get the `AVPlayer` that is currently running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because this may be helpful to someone...

I created a global `AVPlayer` by making it a property of the AppDelegate and initializing it there. I then created an instance of the `AppDelegate` in my `ViewController`, and accessed the global `AVPlayer` from there. I could leave the screen and come back to it from with in the app, and I still had control of the `AVPlayer`.

Comment: Hi, I have same issue, but I can't achieve following your instructions. Do you have any example code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something deeper here, but you need to store a reference to the AVPlayer as an instance variable.

@interface

```
AVPlayer *player;
```

@implementation

```
player = [AVPLayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
```

Then you do stuff to the player reference

```
[player doStuff];
```